# Jquery - Add tag "checked" on input

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a problem, i want to add "checked" when i click on the input but I don't know how to do, here is my jQuery code :

```
jQuery('#myId div input').click(function(){
                                jQuery(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
                            });
```

And this is my HTML code :

```
<form id="myId">
<div class="grid12-12">
<input type="radio" value="292" id="292" class="required-entry">
<label for="292">Ordonnance.jpg</label>
</div>
</form>
```

but the thing is that if I do that, this is what happens, I have this in my tag :

> checked = "checked"

And I want only "checked" in my tag like this

```
<input type="radio" id="292" value="292" checked>
```

if I remove the checked in the jQuery like this :

```
jQuery('#myId div input').click(function(){
                                jQuery(this).attr('', 'checked');
                            });
```

I have an error.

So how can I do that please ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `prop` instead of `attr`, because this is a property, not an attribue.

```
$('#myId div input').click(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

But it is correct that you see `checked="checked"`. This is the same with using `disabled`, it will become `disabled="disabled"`. No problem at all. There are even HTML versions where this type of attribute minimization is forbidden, like `XHTML`. Therefore it is the savest way to use `checked="checked"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you solve it.

`$( "#myId div input" ).prop( "checked", true );
 $( "#myId div input" ).prop( "checked", false );`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an empty attribute to the element its just like saying

```
<input type="radio" id="292" value="292" ="checked " />
```

So you do it like this

```
$(this).attr("checked", true);
```